# Zipping on more than 2 lists in sml

Tags: sml

I am having a problem with tail in my function.I would like to get rid of the tail but I cannot think of a way to do it.I will be happy if someone may assist me figure a way out.

```
fun Rollists (x::nil) = [x]
  | Rollists (xs) =(map hd xs)::Rollists( map tl xs);
```

this function,is supposed to output elements from a given list list as pairs from each list,an larger version of `ListPair.zip`

Comment: What problem are you having? It's sort of hard to solve otherwise. Also, you're missing an openparen in your second case.

Comment: sure,I am trying to implement Quine McCluskey Algorithm,so I would want to add up all prime implicants which cover the original boolean function,then take the cheapest one.so the hard part is this "addition" part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generates pairs from a list of lists based upon the first list:

```
fun generateTuples (lol) =
    let
    (*  Treat the ListOfLists as a database
        table, with the first
        list being a key value column *)
    val keys  = hd(lol)

    (*  and the remaining columns being
        additional fields in its tuple *)
    val records  = tl(lol)

    (*  Pairs the key with each column
        in its record *)
    fun formPairs (aKey,listOfRecords) =
        if null listOfRecords
        then []
        else [aKey,hd(hd listOfRecords)]::
         (formPairs(aKey,tl(listOfRecords)))

    (*  Pops a row's data fields from the record *)
    fun chopLists (listOfRecords)=
        if null listOfRecords
        then []
        else tl(hd(listOfRecords))::
         (chopLists(tl(listOfRecords)))
    in
    (*  Pass the first key value to formPairs
        along with all the records. Then pop
        the first row off the database and call
        generateTuples on the remain *)
    if null keys 
    then []
    else generateTuples(tl(keys)::(chopLists(records)))
         @ formPairs(hd(keys),records)      
    end
```

Example:

```
val list1 = [0,1,2,3,4]
val list2 = [55,66,77,88,99]
val list3 = [10,11,12,13,14]
val list4 = [555,666,777,888,999]
val lols = [list1,list2,list3,list4]

- generateTuples(lols);
val it =
  [[4,99],[4,14],[4,999],[3,88],[3,13],[3,888],[2,77],[2,12],[2,777],[1,66],
   [1,11],[1,666],...] : int list list
```

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted for the output,but the job is pretty done.I would need generateTuples to output sublists with same size as head of the argument of list of lists,that is,concatenating all sublists of generateTuples which start with same element and make sure that this element is only entered once in the new sublist.I will try fixing that now @ben rudgers

Comment: Ignoring the reversal for tail-calls and filtering for duplicates, would the output of  generateTuples(lol) be [[[0,55],[0,66],[0,77],[0,88],[0,99]],...[4,888][4,999]]]?